# set permission in windows 2012 to only copy file

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012

how set permissions in windows 2012 to only user can view file and list foldet and can copy and create file and folder in share folder but user can not read or delete or copy file and folder from share folder?

tanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the equivalent of the *nix sticky bit, so only a file creator can carry out operations in that file?  What if you edit the folder properties/permissions, set "CREATOR" permissions to Allow "Full Control", and "Users" permissions to "List Folder Contents"?